# a bit of a string matching conundrum in excel-vba

Tags: sorting, excel, matching, vba

i'm writing a program at work for a categorizing issue.
i get data in the form of CODE, DESCRIPTION, SUB-TOTAL for example:

```
LIQ013     COGNAC     25
LIQ023     VODKA      21
FD0001     PRETZELS   10
PP0502     NAPKINS    5
```

Now it all generally follows something like this...the problem is my company supplies numerous different bars. So there are like 800 records a month with data like this. My boss wants to breakdown the data so she knows how much we spend on a certain category each month. For example:

```
ALCOHOL 46 
FOOD    10
PAPER   5
```

What I've thought of is I setup a sort of "data-base" which is really a csv text file that contains entries like this:

```
LIQ,COGNAC,ALCOHOL
LIQ,VODKA,ALCOHOL
FD,PRETZELS,FOOD
FD,POPCORN,FOOD
```

I've already written code that imports the database as a worksheet and separates each field into its own column. I want excel to look through the file and when it sees LIQ and COGNAC to assign it the ALCOHOL designator. That way I can use a pivot table to get the category sums. For example I want the final product to look like this:

```
LIQ013     COGNAC     25     ALCOHOL
LIQ023     VODKA      21     ALCOHOL
FD0001     PRETZELS   10     FOOD
PP0502     NAPKINS    5      PAPER
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? My worry is that a single point expression match to JUST the code i.e. just to LIQ without a match to COGNAC as well would maybe result in problems later when there are conflicting descriptions? I'd also like the user to be able to add ledger entries so that the database of recognized terms grows and becomes more expansive and hopefully more accurate.

## EDIT

as per @Marc 's request i'm including my solution:

[code](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1-1HycqztBQTUYmXFpM5lgCxrFwwMJkbMe4gdqe2kyvw) 
 [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Al_4JvWSCtTndER3YVFIRnRBd0p4TndYOWZTb01ENmc&output=html)

please note that this is a pretty dumb-ed down solution. i removed a bunch of the fail-safes and other bits of code that were relevant to a robust code but not to our particular solution.

in order to get this to work there are two parts:

the first is the macro source code
the second is the actual file

because all the fail-safes are removed, the file needs to be imported to excel **exactly** the way it appears. i.e. Sheet1 on the googleDoc should be Sheet1 on the excel, start pasting data at cell "A1". before the macro is run, be sure to select cell "A1" in Sheet1. as i said, there are implementations in the finished product to make it more user friendly! enjoy!

## EDIT2

These links suck. They don't paste well into excel.
If your comfortable with it I can email you the actual workbook. Which would help in preserving the formatting etc.

Comment: Have you looked into the `SUMIF()` functions?  Or even the Subtotals feature of Excel?

Comment: @Marc well you see SUMIF() would work but the items need to be separated by category first.

Comment: That looks like a fun app to work on.

Comment: thanks @HeadofCatering the idea is eventually to make it semi-intelligent. pivot-tables can of course be automatically generated. so once the sorting is done and the database is reasonably robust, then it should be able to take raw data, sort it, categorize it and then automatically generate a sub-total table. the only human input being when an item is not picked up by the database.

Comment: Very cool. Even better if you get to sample the subject matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookup table in a separate sheet.  Column A of the lookup sheet contains the lookup value (e.g. PRETZELS), Column B contains the category (FOOD, ALCOHOL, etc).  In the cells where you want the category to show up in your original sheet (let's use D3 for the result where B3 holds the "PRETZELS" value), type this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,OtherSheet!$A$1:$B$500,2,FALSE)
```

That assumes that your lookup table is in range `A1:B500` of a worksheet named "OtherSheet".

This formula tells Excel to find the lookup value (B3) in column A of your lookup and return the corresponding value from column B of your lookup table.  Absolute references (the `$`) ensure that your formula won't increment cell references when you copy/paste the formula in other cells.

When you get new categories and/or inventory, you can update your lookup table in this one place by just adding new rows to it.

Comment: thanks @Marc, your method is exactly what a co-worker of mine uses. but the issue is that it's not as robust as a macro that does multi-point searches. actually i'm close though. and will post the results probably tomorrow when i can get access to the company's database.

Comment: @franklin, I'm curious what you mean by "multi-point searches" and why my method couldn't be extended to what you're attempting.  I find that using Excel's built-in and well-worn functions is often more reliable than a custom VBA macro.  Also, it sounds like you might have to rerun your macro every time you want to categorize, vs. a formula that would auto-update.  Can you shed some light?

Comment: Hi @Marc, the term i use "multi-point searches" is really just something i made up to describe this search pattern. ideally, what i had in mind was a program that would match the type code LIQ to an alcohol and match a search term i.e. Cognac, Wine, Bourbon, etc. to an alcohol. then there are two points at which it would be confirmed as a match. OTHERWISE it'd be only a 50% match. as the number of searchable terms grows, the relevancy can be determined by the number of points that the fields can be matched to. i don't know if that helps a bit.

Comment: incidentally, VLOOKUP is still looking up an EXACT match of the string. so it's not more/less powerful than Instr() which i predict my implementation to be using.

Comment: @franklin, If you're using a concatenated string, you can emulate the "multi-point search you desire using `VLOOKUP`.  And using `Instr` is fine, but it sounds like you're talking about iterating over the column while using `Instr`.  All I'm saying is the the `VLOOKUP` is already coded to do exactly what you want to write VBA to do.  So why not adapt your parameters to the trusted functions instead of rolling your own function?

Comment: I have the code for my solution if anyone would like to see it. @Marc: I ended up using the pivot-table. Although I realize the elegance and simplicity of your method, I had wanted an automation type script. I literally wanted this functionality to be coded into the workbook. The next step is to fetch that data from SQL so that when I leave the company all this manual sorting garbage can be done with one click.

Comment: @franklin, I'd be curious to see what you came up with.  Can you post an update into your question?